# Grafana openshift monitoring OAuth Proxy: The request is missing a required parameter

Tags: oauth, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I am using a brand new installation of openshift:

```
oc v3.11.0+62803d0-1
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://master.mydomain.fr:8443
openshift v3.11.0+2bcedfc-77
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
```

I have 3 nodes:

```
[root@master centos]# oc get node
NAME                 STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
master.mydomain.fr   Ready     master    1d        v1.11.0+d4cacc0
node1.mydomain.fr    Ready     infra     1d        v1.11.0+d4cacc0
node2.mydomain.fr    Ready     compute   1d        v1.11.0+d4cacc0
node3.mydomain.fr    Ready     compute   1d        v1.11.0+d4cacc0
node4.mydomain.fr    Ready     compute   1d        v1.11.0+d4cacc0
```

I successfully configured everything but now I am trying to access to my grafana dashboards. I created a route:

```
grafana.mydomain.fr
```

I am redirected to the Login Button of the OauthProxy. When I click on Login I am redirected to a blank page with Json:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.","state":"7f3a18c95ae8237d39d35bf8ff317ae4:/"}
```

Here is the URI I am getting:

```
https://master.mydomain.fr:8443/oauth/authorize?approval_prompt=force&client_id=system%3Aserviceaccount%3Aopenshift-monitoring%3Agrafana&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgrafana.mydomain.fr%2Foauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=user%3Ainfo+user%3Acheck-access&state=7f3a18c95ae8237d39d35bf8ff317ae4%3A%2F
```

After looking at the log I am getting:

```
no RBAC policy matched
```

I am pretty sure it is linked to my configuration (maybe the redirect URI is not correct) but to be honnest I don't know how to configure it. Do you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The grafana that you said is using in [Prometheus Cluster Monitoring](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/prometheus_cluster_monitoring.html#prometheus-cluster-monitoring) ? then you should have `cluster-admin` role for using it. Does your account which you are login with have `cluster-admin` role ?

Comment: Hello Yes I am cluster admin. I am using the Prometheus cluster Monitoring (brought with ansible installation)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the exact same issue while trying to expose Prometheus (OpenShift 3.11) and this is how I solved the issue.

As the question does not make it clear about the route name and in case you have created a route other than `grafana` which is the default account that comes with openshift. Then one of the reasons could be the route name and that's because the `serviceAccount` that is being used in the authentication process is expecting to be used with a route named `grafana` according to the section:

```
# Taken from grafana's serviceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    serviceaccounts.openshift.io/oauth-redirectreference.grafana: '{"kind":"OAuthRedirectReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"Route","name":"grafana"}}'
```

This makes the authentication work specifically with a route named `grafana`, so either modify the original route with the desired domain or modify this annotation with the new router that you have created.